# wrapper function bracketing

Tags: javascript, function, wrapper

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm having a difficult time with this multi function call

This bit is running fine

```
$('.pages').live("swiperight", function () {  
    if (!menuStatus) {  
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({  
            marginLeft: "165px",  
        }, 300, function () {  
            menuStatus = true  
        });  
    }  
});
```

and I'd like to add

```
(document).scrollTop(0);
```

so that a user will be taken to the top of long pages as the menu opens... any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Please replace `live()` function with `on()` as it's deprecated since jQuery 1.7 http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use something like this to perform your scroll:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

So if you wanted to add this to your current function as shown: *(you can place it wherever you would like it to occur)*

```
$('.pages').on("swiperight", function () {
    if (!menuStatus) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        //Perform scroll-to-top action
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
});
```

additionally, this could should also work *(as mentioned by Jan)*:

```
$('document').on("swiperight",".pages", function () {
    if (!menuStatus) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        //Perform scroll-to-top action
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: wow... thanks Rion... that was FAST!
but the scrolling works fine... I'd just like to incorporate it into the main function so that the menu opening, status set to true and scroll to the top all occur with the one call

Comment: No problem, I hope it helped.

Comment: Note that `live` has been deprecated. @Rion - can you please reflect the fact in your answer?

Comment: Hmm... I guess `$(document).on("swiperight", ".pages", ...` would be more to the original intention.

Comment: ah... and thank you for that bit about updating my jquery.... I had noticed that the page was occasionally breaking, perhaps that's the reason for the change... thank you all again, this is a loooongg way from VBA!!