# FB swipe action failing

Tags: javascript, action, swipe

related to the
[wrapper function bracketing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133587/wrapper-function-bracketing)
question

Rion and Jan were good enough to make that script work, but it only works for awhile (and is quite unrelated to the added line) so it seem the original code fails, I'm assuming that it's my doing as this FB style thing seems to be everywhere out there. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page it 'breaks' the code. I guess the class of the content area is changing? I'm quite green on this sort of stuff.

If it can't work because of the jquery, no biggie, the Showmenu click works, the swipe effect is just so terrific it would be nice to keep and as the site is based on 1.6.4 I really don't want to re-do it all.

Here's the code

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
});

$(function () {
var menuStatus;

// Show menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function () {
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        });
        return false;
    }
});

$('#menu, .pages').live("swipeleft", function () {
    if (menuStatus) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        });
    }
});

$('.pages').live("swiperight", function () {
    if (!menuStatus) {
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "165px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
});

and the HTML

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html manifest="island.manifest">
<head> 
<title></title> 
<meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<!--webapp stay-->
<!--test-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/add-to-home/touch-icon-iphone.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/add-to-home/touch-icon-iphone.png"/>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="" class="noeffect" style="height:50px;border-right:none;padding:15px;background:#075191;"><img src="images/YouIn.png" width="120"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="contentLink" rel="external"  >Main </a></li>
    <li><a href="nav_2.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >January 30, 2013</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="nav_3.html" class="contentLink" rel="external"  style="border-right:solid 0px #9a9999" >January 31, 2013 </a></li>
    <li><a href="nav_4.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >February 1, 2013 </a></li>
    <li><a href="nav_5.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >February 2, 2013</a></li>              
    <li><a href="nav_6.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" style="color:red;text-align:center">Game Day!!!</a></li>
    <li><a href="nav_7.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >February 4, 2013 </a></li>
    <li><a href="nav_8.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >Map </a></li>      
    <li><a href="nav_9.html" class="contentLink" rel="external" >Contact Staff </a></li>        
    <li><a target="_blank" href="" class="noeffect" style="min-height:300px;border-top:solid 1px #3c7db3;padding:250px 0 0 15px;background:#075191;"><img src="images/YouIn.png" width="120"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="page" class="pages" id="home">
<div data-role="header" style="min-height: 80px; background:#075191; ">
<span><a href="#" class="showMenu" style="float:left;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;"><img src="images/MenuPSD3C.png" height= "64"></a></span>
<span ><a href="index.html" style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;"><img src="images/add-to-home/touch-icon-iphone.png" height= "64" ></a></span>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content" style="min-height:1400px;border-top:solid #b2b3b5 1px">
    content stuff
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fullscreen() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('noeffect')) {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
fullscreen();
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: am I allowed to answer my own questions? :)
it's an iOS issue, don't worry Apple, I still luv ya!!

Answer (score 0):

insert after your jquery ref

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  (function (window) {
// This library re-implements setTimeout, setInterval, clearTimeout, clearInterval for iOS6.
// iOS6 suffers from a bug that kills timers that are created while a page is scrolling.
// This library fixes that problem by recreating timers after scrolling finishes (with interval correction).
// This code is free to use by anyone (MIT, blabla).
// Original Author: rkorving@wizcorp.jp
var timeouts = {};
var intervals = {};
var orgSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
var orgSetInterval = window.setInterval;
var orgClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
var orgClearInterval = window.clearInterval;
// To prevent errors if loaded on older IE.
if (!window.addEventListener) return false;
function createTimer(set, map, args) {
    var id, cb = args[0],
        repeat = (set === orgSetInterval);

    function callback() {
        if (cb) {
            cb.apply(window, arguments);
            if (!repeat) {
                delete map[id];
                cb = null;
            }
        }
    }
    args[0] = callback;
    id = set.apply(window, args);
    map[id] = {
        args: args,
        created: Date.now(),
        cb: cb,
        id: id
    };
    return id;
}

function resetTimer(set, clear, map, virtualId, correctInterval) {
    var timer = map[virtualId];
    if (!timer) {
        return;
    }
    var repeat = (set === orgSetInterval);
    // cleanup
    clear(timer.id);
    // reduce the interval (arg 1 in the args array)
    if (!repeat) {
        var interval = timer.args[1];
        var reduction = Date.now() - timer.created;
        if (reduction < 0) {
            reduction = 0;
        }
        interval -= reduction;
        if (interval < 0) {
            interval = 0;
        }
        timer.args[1] = interval;
    }
    // recreate
    function callback() {
        if (timer.cb) {
            timer.cb.apply(window, arguments);
            if (!repeat) {
                delete map[virtualId];
                timer.cb = null;
            }
        }
    }
    timer.args[0] = callback;
    timer.created = Date.now();
    timer.id = set.apply(window, timer.args);
}
window.setTimeout = function () {
    return createTimer(orgSetTimeout, timeouts, arguments);
};
window.setInterval = function () {
    return createTimer(orgSetInterval, intervals, arguments);
};
window.clearTimeout = function (id) {
    var timer = timeouts[id];
    if (timer) {
        delete timeouts[id];
        orgClearTimeout(timer.id);
    }
};
window.clearInterval = function (id) {
    var timer = intervals[id];
    if (timer) {
        delete intervals[id];
        orgClearInterval(timer.id);
    }
};
//check and add listener on the top window if loaded on frameset/iframe
var win = window;
while (win.location != win.parent.location) {
    win = win.parent;
}
win.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    // recreate the timers using adjusted intervals
    // we cannot know how long the scroll-freeze lasted, so we cannot take that into account
    var virtualId;
    for (virtualId in timeouts) {
        resetTimer(orgSetTimeout, orgClearTimeout, timeouts, virtualId);
    }
    for (virtualId in intervals) {
        resetTimer(orgSetInterval, orgClearInterval, intervals, virtualId);
    }
});
}(window));
</script>
```